# VNA Tuning in Enclosure -- LiPo Battery Detuning Antenna

Tags: rf, impedance-matching

I've got a finished design, that I tuned the matching network using bare boards.

Say for example, my tuned TX board has an over-the-air 3 meter reading on my spectrum analyzer at -50dbm. (This is at VSWR 1.2:1).

When I put the TX board, into the transmitter enclosure I see significant signal attenuation.  My tuned TX board now has an over-the-air 3 meter reading on my spectrum analyzer at -75dbm. (At unknown VSWR).

Unfortunately, in the 4 months since I tuned these boards, my USB VNA is not working, so I had to re-order another one, so I can't measure the impedance in the enclosure quite yet.

I have chalked it up more to the plastic attenuating the signal, as opposed to a massive impedance change.

Is it possible there is that much change to the impedance when a perfectly tuned TX board is put into an enclosure?

**UPDATE:** It's definently not the plastic per se, weakening the signal. The TX signal gets weak when the LiPo battery is positioned in a certain way in the enclosure.  Not sure if that is a change in the impedance or some other electro-phenomenon, until I get a working VNA to make the measurements.

**RESULTS:**

TX bare boards in your hand, battery hanging in free space: -50dbm.

TX in the enclosure, with battery inside (10mm away from the board – huge space): -75dbm.

TX in the enclosure, with battery hanging outside the enclosure: -48dbm

--

(I tried shielding the battery with copper tape, it doesn't seem like it is some LiPo magic anti-RF waves are being emitted and messing with the transmitter IC or something else).

Comment: Why don’t your tell the design details instead hand waving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Mills pointed out, the battery is a pretty large metallic object in the antenna near field.

And Tony's suspicions were correct.  The impedance was just getting majorly pulled off.

I got a working VNA and came back in to fine tune the TX this afternoon.

Initially I saw the TX VSWR go from 1.2:1, to ~18:1 or so when I put everything in the enclosure.

I went through and tuned the TX to 2:1 VSWR with one series inductor in a PI network. I could change the inductor value and probably get this to 1:1 with two more passes.

To date I've been ear-marking my TX board vs. a manufacturer sample module of the TX IC.  The sample module is an over-the-air 3 meter reading of -49dBm on my bench.  I had that module measured at an FCC lab, and it is a touch over the FCC limit.

For perspective, my non-functional TX boards in the enclosure + battery, went from -75dBm, to an over-the-air 3 meter reading of -45.78dBm.  We are smoking the sample module now (AND WAY OVER THE FCC LIMIT!  What an irony).

I did some measurements with our remote enclosure which is an ABS plastic, and I didn't see any significant impedance change.  But the battery was in fact the major contributor, even at 20mm away.

Our plastic manufacturer has mentioned that polycarbonate plastics (PC), in their experience do attenuate more.  I've got the RX to tune now in the PC enclosure.

Similiarly with the RX,  the VSWR was getting pulled off to 34:1 VSWR.  Minor re-tune and it's good with a LiPo battery nearly 3mm away from the antenna.

Those LiPo batteries really can do a number on your tuning.

Comment: How did you connect the VNA to the antenna? Not with a conductive wire I hope. If your battery, under 10 cm with leads, pulled it off frequency so badly, imagine what the long coax will do! Suggestions: use a ton of high impedance small ferrite beads, a mix of 43 and 61 material, on the last half metre of coax. Feel the coax for RF, by running your hand down the cable and watching the VSWR for changes; if it moves then the cable is part of the antenna. Finally, test with the on-board transmitter itself.

Comment: @Tomnexus -- that's good advice seeing how I've drilled out the RX enclosure and made a big project out of this already.  No harm in ordering a few beads and putting them on the coax pigtail. I think the coax lead is about 5 inches.  I'm not 100% on the transmission line algebra at 433MHz, but I think that is long enough. The TX is kind of a wash, since we are over the FCC limit.  The RX though, of course we want that as close to 1:1 as possible.  No wonder you RF folks always have a backup-supply of tin foil hats -- it's never ending. ;)

Comment: Off the cuff, I did a measurement with the RX-in-the-enclosure with my tuning values from using the coax without ferrite beads VS. RX-without-enclosure.  The RX IC doesn't have an RSSI, so my test with a weak-over-the-air signal from a signal generator.  I also tested the sample RX module.  The RX module sample and my freespace tuned RX board started to not demodulate an over-the-air signal at -47dBm from my signal generator.  My newly tuned in-the-enclosure RX board also degraded at -47dBm.  I also had to run 22 gauge wires with GND and the RX IC output out of the enclosure.

Comment: Ok. It's not just the short coax, but the whole VNA, its USB cable, etc. This could have a major effect on the tuning. The same for signal wires, any gauge. Find the small fair-rite beads, 6 mm OD, 3.2 mm ID, 12.5 mm long, these have good impedance and are small and cheap.

Comment: Appreciate a specific recommendation on the beads! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds not just possible but likely, especially once you are working with decently high frequencies. This is also a common problem with antennas where their center frequency will shift (sometimes so much it no longer covers the band of interest).
Depending on the material, it could be the plastic being very lossy (PVC is for instance very lossy at certain frequencies due the it being polarized) or the fact that your plastic is a dielectric that changes the impedance of your lines.

Comment: Joren, I definently can say it is not the the plastic attenuating the signal.  I put the TX in front of like 2 ten gallon pails, and the plastic itself doesn't weaken the signal that much.  Usually I'd have a working VNA to confirm if the impedance is changing some catastrophic way.  The odd thing is that what I have found is that the position of the LiPo battery is  throwing this whole thing off.

Comment: End of the day the battery is a big conductive object that you are putting in the near field of the antenna, of course it detunes it, how could it not?

Comment: @DanMills, I guess I didn't anticipate this much detuning. We just finished the molds.  The LiPo is nearly 20mm away from the board, so I would not have thought you would have that much of an effect.  I would have thought the large metal object in the near field would be more of a blocker, than a detuner.  I can assure you, the Lipo it's a better detuner than a blocker far as I can tell.  I have to get a new VNA, (and many swear words later, to test this thing in an enclosure...), to confirm how far off it is getting pulled.

Comment: 20mm is not a very large fraction of a wavelength at (I assume) a few GHz. At 2.4Ghz you have a wavelength in free space of over 12cm, at 5GHz you are still at ~6cm.....  It will detune and also change the radiation pattern, being as a conductor effectively changes the impedance of the space in its vicinity. I would bet it is ALSO lossy, as the materials are unlikely to be particularly good reflectors at the low microwave bands.

Comment: Isn’t this for a 4xx MHx Tx

Comment: Yes, this is at 433MHz.  I don't want to dump out too many design details, and get yelled at for design review!   I think the salient issue here is that yes, a LiPo could in fact influence the impedance and pull it off.  The plastic doesn't seem to be the contributing factor of significance in this case.  I'll put up some photos and whatnot once I get a replacement VNA -- I may even buy a real used VNA after this go around.

Comment: One thing that might help is adding a common mode choke to the battery leads, with a 70cm band radio you might actually be just seeing capacitive loading returned to ground via the power cables, an electrically short aerial (guessing very electrically short) will be quite a high voltage affair and thus prone to capacitive loading.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine a USB VNA being very stable in a plastic enclosure.  Shielding is critical with tuning access holes to isolate the interference effects of  near fields, dielectric, stray external conductors and reflections from hands.  In the 70's all our 500MHz Tx's were put in milled aluminum cases with lids. In the 90's all our ceramic custom hybrid 1GHz VCO's TX/Rx had tin plated brass shields.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing, something goofy -- the LiPo battery position in the plastic is affecting the TX signal strength.  Pull the LiPo out of the enclosure, and the TX is back to VSWR 1.2:1.  I use a MiniVNA Tiny (similar to that Pocket VNA), I'm envisioning a long coax lead to the TX board in the plastic.  This kills me to find my long trusty USB VNA, literally dead in a box when I need it to the most...

Comment: That tells me your Tx tuning is too high impedance.

Comment: Is something oscillating? to move some major bit of metal, and have a 25dB change in power, is either major de-tuning or oscillation IMHO

Comment: What do you mean by oscillation in this context?  Honestly, i am a bit stymied, the LiPo is far away from everything and nice and tidy in the enclosure.  Should get a new vna in a week...  Disposable vna i guess.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf -- what I am thinking is yes, there are active oscillators on two IC (TX IC and the MCU) so there are things oscillating.... but I don't think that's what you are getting at?